# Converting special font characters to ascii equivalents

Tags: c#, text, unicode

I'm trying to create an algorithm in C# to convert characters like  and  to characters like `a` and `B`. I first thought create a dictionary with a string and list string, but I'm wondering if there is already something out there I don't know about that can help? Like something as simple as converting to ascii char codes?

I'm unsure on how to proceed as there are a lot of fonts.

Comment: fyi this isn't a font. this is just additional unicode codepoints

Comment: Those aren't single characters. This has nothing to do with fonts

Comment: Try [String.Normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.normalizationform?view=net-6.0) with either FormKC or FormKD eg `s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)`